# Spark, Scala not able to create view appropriately after reading from file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark and scala on jdk1.8.I am new to Scala.

**I am reading a text file (pat1.txt) that looks like :**

[image]

**Now I am reading that file from my scala code as :**

```
val sqlContext = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()  
sqlContext.read
    .format(externalEntity.getExtractfileType)
    .option("compression", externalEntity.getCompressionCodec)
    .option("header", if (externalEntity.getHasHeader.toUpperCase == "Y") "true" else "false")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("delimiter", externalEntity.getExtractDelimiter)
    .load(externalEntity.getFilePath)
    .createOrReplaceTempView(externalEntity.getExtractName)
```

**And then making a query as from my scala code:**

```
val queryResult = sqlContext.sql(myQuery)
```

**and output is generated as :**

```
queryResult
 .repartition(LteGenericExtractEntity.getNumberOfFiles.toInt)
 .write.format("csv")
 .option("compression", LteGenericExtractEntity.getCompressionCodec)
 .option("delimiter", LteGenericExtractEntity.getExtractDelimiter)
 .option("header", "true"")
 .save(s"${outputDirectory}/${extractFileBase}")
```

**Now when the 'myQuery' above is**

```
select * from PAT1
```

The program is generating o/p as (**notice the extra line with "value" that was not part of the file**). Basically the program is not able to to identify the "," separated columns in the input file and in the output it creates 1 column under the header that is named as "value". So the output file looks like :

[image]

**If I change  'myQuery' as :**

```
select p1.FIRST_NAME, p1.LAST_NAME,p1.HOBBY  from PAT1 p1
```

**It throws exception as:**

[image]

**My input can be in any format ( like can be text/csv and can have compression) and output will always be in .csv**

I am getting hard time to understand how to change the read part so the created view can have columns appropriately.Can I get help on that.

Comment: I think you have to change read format to csv in input like sqlContext.read.format("csv")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like csv file, but with .txt extension.
You could try the following:

1. Rad this file as `csv` with extra options like `spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("path/to/file")`
2. After reading file as you did, just specify the schema of the dataframe as:

```
    sqlContext.read.format("text")
          .option("compression", "none")
          .option("delimiter", ",")
          .option("header", "true")
          .load("/tmp/pat1")
          .toDF("first_name", "last_name", "hobby")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The use case is : 1> Input file can be in any format,2> Need to dynamically generate the schema , 3> Need to generate a view on that so that we can query on that view. query result will go the output in .cvs format            Hence I can not change it to DF as I do not know the schema actually

Comment: Had to read as csv even though it was a text file and added ".option("inferSchema", "true")" after that my reading worked right